# How to detect if a JS variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
// mystring contains dynamic text. Sometimes can be
// null
var a = mystring.split(" ");
var proc = a[0] + " " + a[1];
```

If `a` does not contain text, after `split` proc is undefined. If I try to assing its value to a textbox the result is "undefined":

```
mytextbox.val(proc);
```

[image]

So I need a way to make that proc has always a value, at least an empty string.

Comment: I think `mytextbox.val(proc || '')` would do it.

Comment: @jAndy `if` didn't work. It mathes always as undefined

Comment: @a_maar: `if( mystring && mystring.length ) { // all the rest }`

Comment: @Jack: that would fail because you cannot call split on mystring when mystring is undefined

Comment: Is `mystring` really `null`? I think you mean the empty string.

Comment: @hereandnow78 Yep, didn't think that one through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use

```
(mystring || " ")
```

which will evaluate to `mystring` if it is not `null`, or `" "` if it is.

Or, you can just put an `if` statement around the whole thing:

```
if (mystring != null) {
    // stuff
} else {
    var proc = "";
}
```

Comment: not a good usecase for a logical `OR` here imho. It shouldn't do all the logic if `mystring` is undef or empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
var proc = "";
if (mystring !== null) { // omit this if you're sure it's a string
    var a = mystring.split(" ");
    if (a.length > 1) {
        proc = a[0] + " " + a[1];
    }
}
```

I'm quite sure your `proc` is not `undefined`, but the string `" undefined"`.

Comment: why negating the logic ? Reads positive much clearer, no ? `if( mystring && mystring.length)`

Comment: @jAndy: You mean the `null` logic? I'm still not sure whether the OP really has null or just an empty string, so I wanted to make it explicit. Btw, `mystring.length` is not enought to check to prevent `a[1]` from being `undefined`.